# Redshift of a reflected photon from a solar sail

Tags: visible-light, energy-conservation, momentum, solar-sails

Can someone help me understand my mistake here?
I'm thinking of a photon travelling with momentum $p=h/\lambda$ which reflects off a solar sail of mass $m$ travelling with momentum $p_0$ in the same direction. Before the reflection, the total momentum is $p+p_0$ and after it is $-p'+p_1$ where $p'$ is the magnitude of the reflected photon's momentum and $p_1$ is the sail's new momentum. Conservation of momentum and energy then requires
$$p+p_0 = -p'+p_1$$ and
$$pc + \frac{p_0^2}{2m} = p'c + \frac{p_1^2}{2m}$$
if the sail is travelling at much less than relativistic speeds. But then solving the resulting quadratic for $p_1$ I get the entirely unreasonable
$$p_1 = 4m\left\{-c \pm \sqrt{c^2+\frac{2}{m}\left(\frac{p_0^2}{2m}+p_0c+2pc\right)}\right\}$$
What have I done wrong?

Comment: The reflection as a change of direction should result in a change of impulse. No need to assume shift of frequency (red shift) if change of direction (ex)changes momentum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small error in your math by the way - the factor of $4$ should be a factor of $1$ - check the denominator of the quadratic equation.

Why is this so unreasonable? At a glance, it looks like the momentum of the sail is a bit larger than what it started out with. If I make the reasonable assumptions that:

- The sail is non-relativistic $\frac{p_0}{mc} = \frac{v}{c} \ll 1$
- The energy of the photon is much less than $mc^2$

and use the approximation $\sqrt{1-x}\approx 1-\frac{x}{2}\;{\rm for}\;x\ll1$, your answer reduces to:

$$p_1 \approx p_0+2p$$

This should look familiar - it's like a ball of mass $m$ colliding elastically with a ball of mass $M$ with $m\ll M$.

Comment: Thanks: I'd missed this point. So the redshift necessary to conserve energy comes from the neglected terms in your approximation: since otherwise p=p'?

Comment: @lauren96 Right - the point of the approximation is just to show that the answer makes intuitive sense. My second assumption (bullet point) implies vanishing redshift. Of course if you want accuracy you need to use the un-approximated expression.

Comment: Thanks-- I find if I expand out the square root further and reject terms smaller than order $1/(mc)^3$ I get a redshift of, to first order, $1/\lambda' = 1/\lambda(1-2v_0/c)$. That does seem reasonable (and small).

Comment: I am not sure if the absorbed & reflected photon loses energy in the process, it should since there is transfer of momentum. So does the photon lose energy/red shifted ?

Comment: @Hammar In reality there is a redshift, see my comments above.

Comment: But, how exactly the red-shift will happen if the atom only absorb & emit  specific frequencies; if the emitted photon red-shifted it will imply unnatural behavior. When I thought about it, I assumed that when the photon created(in star for ex.) it take momentum from the star by pushing the star back little which mean no red-shift accrue or at least this what made since to me.

Comment: "What actually happens is that from the reflectors point of view the photons momentum stays the same but from a 'stationery' point of view the photons are red-shifted and thus lose momentum." What do you think of this explanation ?

Comment: I wonder about the change of direction of the photon. Photon are considered to have no rest mass - so they do not  exchange directions with the reflecting mass?